# Power BI Dataset execute-queries API DAX Query Issues

Tags: powerbi

I am leveraging the below API to execute queries on dataset:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries

this is the table on which I want to execute the queries:
[image]

Below is the query that I am leveraging/executing :

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(DataSharkX[EmployeeID],FILTER(DataSharkX,DataSharkX[EmployeeID] = MAX(DataSharkX[EmployeeID])))
```

But I am getting the below error:

[image]

{"error":{"code":"DatasetExecuteQueriesError","pbi.error":{"code":"DatasetExecuteQueriesError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DetailsMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Query (1, 28) The syntax for '[EmployeeID]' is incorrect. (SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(DataSharkX[EmployeeID],FILTER(DataSharkX,DataSharkX[EmployeeID] = MAX(DataSharkX[EmployeeID]))))."}},{"code":"AnalysisServicesErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"3238920194"}}]}}}

But the same query, we are able to execute to create a table
[image]

So can someone explain what I am doing wrong via the REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put [EVALUATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/evaluate-statement-dax) keyword before your DAX query, so it becomes something like this:

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        DataSharkX[EmployeeID], 
        FILTER(
            DataSharkX,
            DataSharkX[EmployeeID] = MAX(DataSharkX[EmployeeID])
        )
    )
```